# How to generate unique file name using jfilechooser?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I am using jfilechooser to generate a new file but **user requirement is to compare if the generated file already exists in the drive or not. If it already exists then generate a new file name** and if it doesn't exist then generate the file.

So I am giving my code which is used to generate a file in any drive location.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser dialog = new JFileChooser();
        int dialogResult = dialog.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (dialogResult==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            String filePath = dialog.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                document.open();
                document.add(new Paragraph("File with path " + filePath));
                document.close();
            }
            catch(DocumentException de) {
                de.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some numeric suffix to your file name. E.g. `fileName01`, `fileName02` etc. You can easily increase the numeric postfix if a file with this name already exists.

Also you can use `File#createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix)` method for such file name generation.

Comment: but sir i use jfilechooser to generate the file name like z:\\test.pdf but when we again try to save next file in the z:\\ location first check test.pdf name is already exit or not if exit then generated new pdf file name .please send the logic its very requirement from our project

Comment: @satish basically it's not your responsibility to generate new file name in this dialog. Look how it's implemented in MS Word. When you try to save file and file you are trying to save is already exist you give 3 options: 'Replace existing file' (just rewrite exist file), 'Save changes with different file name' (open dialog again, ask user about another file name), 'Merge file content' (if it's possible). I think in your dialog you should propose the first 2 options and don't auto generate file name at all

Comment: so how can i implement above your points of you .user requirement is same as you think so plesase send me the logic to resolve my problem